# UIPopoverController moves strangely on iOS 7 when keyboard appears

Tags: ios7, uipopovercontroller

I have a UIPopoverController with a text field in it. On iOS 6, when the user taps the text field and the popover happens to be in the way of the keyboard sliding onscreen, the popover moves nicely out of the way.

On iOS 7, it flies to the edge of the screen. It's ridiculous.

Is this just a bug in iOS 7? Is there a way to control this behavior in iOS 7 that didn't exist before?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using an UISplitViewController?

Comment: I have the same bug, and didn't find solve yet

Comment: I am facing similar issue for iOS6 also. So it is not iOS version specific bug. It might be default functionality, but it is weird.

Answer (score 7):

Try to change `permittedArrowDirections` from `UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny` to `UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft | UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight` in -

> (void)presentPopoverFromRect:(CGRect)rect inView:(UIView *)view permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirections animated:(BOOL)animated;

Comment: This does seem to mitigate the problem...though it feels like a workaround more than a solution. But thanks!

Comment: Another solution - you can change popover size before keyboard will show. see this gist https://gist.github.com/pingwinator/7235232

Comment: I was having some problems with the UIPopoverController presenting itself from the correct rect, then animating itself to a (seemingly) random position on the screen. This solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is a problem with the arrow direction for popovers.
This forum post is related and seems to have more info
https://devforums.apple.com/message/873738#873738

https://devforums.apple.com/message/885612#885612